# transform translate using javascript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, css, hamburger-menu

So i am trying to make a hamburger menu using some easy JavaScript, turns out it isn't so easy. for some reason my transform translate doesn't work.

my javascript code:

```
function hamburger() {
  var x = document.getElementById("links");
  if (x.style.transform === "translateX(0)") {
    x.style.transform === "translateX(100%)";
  } else {
    x.style.transform === "translateX(0)";
  }
}
```

my css:

```
#links {
    position: absolute;
    width: 90%;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 50px;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #dedede;
    min-height: calc(100vh - 50px);
    /*transform: translateX(100%);*/
}
```

Comment: Instead of using brittle inline styles, you're better off toggling a class, like `.open`. You JavaScript handles the class, your CSS file handles the styles. Easier to maintain if you wanted to add a second style like `opacity`, too!

Comment: `x.style.transform === "translateX(100%)";` is a **comparison** not an assignment

Comment: Is this `x.style.transform === "translateX(100%)";` a typo inside if statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only in `if()` condition `===` is allowed and in your code you have it in `if(){...}`
so try changing your code to

```
function hamburger() {
  var x = document.getElementById("links");
  if (x.style.transform === "translateX(0)") {
    x.style.transform = "translateX(100%)";
  } else {
    x.style.transform = "translateX(0)";
  }
}
```

**NOTE :** `=` is used to assign values and `===` is used for checking conditions.

Answer (score 1):

With `x.style` you're trying to access to the inline style attribute and not the properties inside your style declarations. (Your code is also trying to make an assignment with a comparison operator as a side note)

You could more easily toggle a classname instead:

Javascript

```
// cache a reference to the #links element
var x = document.getElementById("links");

function hamburger() {
  x.classList.toggle('translated');
}
```

CSS

```
#links {
    position: absolute;
    width: 90%;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 50px;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #dedede;
    min-height: calc(100vh - 50px);
    transform: translateX(0);
}

#links.translated {
    transform: translateX(100%);
}
```